# Can I use multiple preact versions on one site without conflicts

Tags: preact

I want to make a library that can be loaded on other websites.
Because of that I want to be sure that my plugin code can't conflict with the website code.

I'm researching the possibility to use Preact, because its very small and offers a lot of functionality.

The library need to work for every framework the website is using. It doesn't need to have the same api as the website framework. But it still needs to work.

When the website framework is different then Preact I guess it doesn't conflict, so that isn't a problem. But I guess it is a problem when the website uses Preact 7.2.1 and the library is using Preact 8.2.6.

I don't want that it conflicts with code and also not all events should be available to the website. The library should be self contained.

Thinks that I was thinking about:
- Is it enough to execute preact and all the library code in a anonymous function so it is contained?
- jQuery changes restores the $ after executing, don't think that is going to work for Preact.

Do you know a solution to this problem (or does it work out of the box)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that it doesnt interfer because it is not setting global variables

https://github.com/developit/preact/issues/954#issuecomment-350284112